# ExpiresDefault getting set to one year for any value in apache mod_expires

Tags: apache, http-headers, mod-expires

I have tried following code in my httpd.conf file to set the expires header in apache

```
<IfModule expires_module>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault A0  // have also tried "access plus 1 second"
</ifModule>
```

But when I look at the reponse headers it is being set to 1 year from now. Am I missing something here.

[image]

Comment: `<IfModule mod_expires>` ?

Comment: @DusanBajic This is name of the module I have loaded

Comment: The string which identifies the module for use in the `LoadModule` directive is [Module Identifier](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/module-dict.html#ModuleIdentifier). The name used by the `<IfModule>` directive is [Source file](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html)